# How to add Duplicate Entries to Hashtable in C#

Tags: c#, hashtable

I am having a xml ...there are some duplicate entries in that how to add those in Hashtable

```
        <hashdata>
        <data key="A" value="A1"/>
        <data key="B" value="B1"/>
        <data key="C" value="C1"/>
        <data key="D" value="D1"/>
        <data key="E" value="E1"/>
        <data key="F" value="F1"/>
        <data key="A" value="A2"/>
        <data key="D" value="D2"/>
        <data key="F" value="F2"/>
        </hashdata>


        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(@"test.xml");
        XmlNodeList xnode = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/hashdata/data");
        Hashtable hst = new Hashtable();
        for (int iCount = 0; iCount < xnode.Count; iCount++)
        {
            hst[xnode[iCount].Attributes["key"].Value.ToString()] = xnode[iCount].Attributes["value"].Value.ToString();
        }
```

How to solve this

Comment: You store the value as a collection.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: @user2046631: Please don't add code in comments. Edit your question instead. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: but its overwriting the values

Answer (score 4):

This is by design - each key in a `Hashtable` is unique, and assigning a value to a key that already exists will overwrite that value when using the indexing operator `[]`.

I would suggest a couple of changes:

First, avoid using `Hashtable` altogether if possible, and instead use one of the generic collections e.g. `Dictionary<,>`.

If you do in fact need multiple values per key, you can probably use something along the following lines:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (XmlNode node in xnode)
{
    var key = node.Attributes["key"].Value;
    List<string> values;
    if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out values))
    {
        values = new List<string>();
        dict.Add(key, values);
    }
    values.Add(node.Attributes["value"].Value);
}
```

Or to use Linq to construct the dictionary, you can use something like:

```
var dict = xnode.Cast<XmlNode>()
                .GroupBy(n => n.Attributes["key"].Value, n => n.Attributes["value"].Value)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

If you absolutely have to use `Hashtable` then the above can be adapted as follows:

```
var hash = new Hashtable();
foreach (XmlNode node in xnode)
{
    var key = node.Attributes["key"].Value;
    var values = (List<string>)hash[key];
    if (values == null)
    {
        values = new List<string>();
        hash.Add(key, values);
    }
    values.Add(node.Attributes["value"].Value);
}
```

Comment: But my task is do in Hashtable only ..is thr any way

Comment: @user2046631 I have updated my answer with a Hashtable version, but as indicated, unless there is a legitimate reason to use the non-generic collection, the generic version is considerably cleaner (no casting from `object`, use of `TryGetValue` etc.)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot , Hashtable Key is unique.
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx)

Try List etc.